# Python 3.4 & Netifaces - Get one specific IPv4 address

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address

I am trying to get (or return) an IP address from my mobile internet interface, which changes everytime I replug it into my laptop. I have found the interface using netiface:

```
import netiface

netifaces.interfaces()
```

Which gave me bunch of interfaces, and say that the interface I need is xxx123-yyy456, so I do the following:

```
myIface = netifaces.ifaddressess('xxx123-yyy456')
myIface[netifaces.AF_INET]
```

Which shows me these addresses (numbers changed):

```
[{'addr': '10.0.0.1', 'broadcast': '10.0.0.2', 'netmask': '255.255.255.255'}]
```

Which I'm not sure if it is a list or dictionary, thus I'm struggling with getting the ip address out of it.  I've got only as far as getting a list of three words:

```
addr
broadcast
netmask
```

What I need is the address number after 'addr':, so I can work with it and call for it later on. For example like:

```
myIp = <the IP the interface curently has>
print(myIp)
```

So that everytime I replug my mobile internet interface I would each time get the new address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list, containing one element, a dictionary. The square brackets denote a list, and the curly denote the dictionary within.

```
>>> results = [{'addr': '10.0.0.1', 'broadcast': '10.0.0.2', 'netmask': '255.255.255.255'}]
>>> results[0]
{'addr': '10.0.0.1', 'broadcast': '10.0.0.2', 'netmask': '255.255.255.255'}
>>> results[0]['addr']
'10.0.0.1'
```